# Passing Img URL from EventListener to Rendering Function

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener

Good Day,

I am trying to pass an uploaded image URL (`userImageURL`) from an Eventlistener to a main function (`init()`) I am using to render a 3d model (using three.js).  However, the `init()` function in my current code is not picking up the change, it's only picking up the empty string for `userImageURL` from the global declaration. What can I do to make the `init()` function's console.log pick up on an EventListener change, when the init function needs to be the first to run?

Here is my code:

```
var userImageURL = '';

//
var img1_input = document.getElementById('img1-input')

img1_input.addEventListener('change', async function(e) {
    //file reader object
    var userImage = e.target.files[0];
    userImageURL = URL.createObjectURL( userImage );
    console.log(userImageURL);
    init(userImageURL);
})

function init(userimg1) {
    console.log(userimg1);

     //RENDERING FUNCTIONALITY IS HERE


)

init();
```

When tested individually, the init functionality and image upload funcitonality work fine - the issue only occurs when trying to pass the `userImageURL` to the `init()` function.

Comment: If you're using an `async` function, it looks like you should add `await` somewhere.

Comment: @Marquizzo thank you for the input. The async was something I was just trying out. With an await on the init() function, I receive an error in VSCode stating that no affect has taken place.